# Plants with nutritional requirements similar to Cannabis

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, nutrition, agriculture

What are some short plants that preferably could be grown indoor which have similar nutritional requirements (in terms of N-P-K ratio, doses etc.) as Cannabis?

The purpose of this is testing a mineral fertilizer for Cannabis, without actually growing Cannabis as it is illegal in my country.

I was looking into [Cannabaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabaceae) family and found out that Hops are closely related. However, due to its size/height it won't be convenient to grow it at home. Also, I'm not sure if being in the same family implies similar nutritional needs.

Plus bonus for valuable/exotic plants.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, I’m voting to close this question because it seems like [Gardening.SE] would be a better fit, but please don't crosspost (instead request migration). ———— In addition, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome Although I'm not new to SE generally (been here for almost 10 years already), I've taken the tour and looked into How to Ask. I didn't find anything new or specific to this SE. There's a clear question in my post (well, I'll add a question mark). It is a general question "about biological concepts". It is not anything personal, philosophical, ethical or having many possible answers. It is well tagged. Regarding cross-posting: as I'm happy to accept both some plant names and/or directions to research myself - I'm expecting the former from Gardening.SE and the latter from here.

Comment: As for the research done - you can see I've started looking into the plant family. Of course before asking this question I've googled it only to get names of plants that have similar leaves or otherwise are visually similar. That's not what I'm looking for. With all due respect, I'm not expecting scientific papers from Gardening.SE (which I expect to get those here) and vice versa - probably there could be people with practical experience and name a plant right away which is improbable here.